# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. when trying to install ping module

Tags: python, module, ping

```
sh: ping: command not found

WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting ping
  Using cached ping-0.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/q3/1cj5lfqn0ds0plbtnv9tqr4r0000gn/T/pip-install-4fgeslm7/ping/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/q3/1cj5lfqn0ds0plbtnv9tqr4r0000gn/T/pip-install-4fgeslm7/ping/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/q3/1cj5lfqn0ds0plbtnv9tqr4r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-p_o79ek6
         cwd: /private/var/folders/q3/1cj5lfqn0ds0plbtnv9tqr4r0000gn/T/pip-install-4fgeslm7/ping/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/q3/1cj5lfqn0ds0plbtnv9tqr4r0000gn/T/pip-install-4fgeslm7/ping/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        from ping import __version__
      File "/private/var/folders/q3/1cj5lfqn0ds0plbtnv9tqr4r0000gn/T/pip-install-4fgeslm7/ping/ping.py", line 196
        except socket.error, (errno, msg):
                           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i have tried many solutions but none work, p[lease assist me

Comment: You need to give us more context information.... what did you try to install? ah.. the ping command... put that into description and remove it from the headline..

You need to edit your question for better readability and to make your question understandable.

Please also give info which command(s) you used and give more info on context (which OS, which environments/versions...)

Answer (score 0):

This package is for Python 2 only. It is no longer maintained ([the latest commit](https://bitbucket.org/delroth/python-ping/src/default/) was in the 2010 year) so there is little hope that it will be ported to Python 3.

You can use [pythonping](https://github.com/alessandromaggio/pythonping) package instead:

```
from pythonping import ping

ping('127.0.0.1', verbose=True)
```